# Location of ruby-gtk2 library files moved in 17.10?

Tags: scripts, 17.10, libraries, ruby

I am trying to use Rubyripper (a CD ripping program that is downloadable from here: http://code.google.com/p/rubyripper) on Ubuntu 17.10. It is a script and a bunch of files; you install the dependencies and run the script. I have used it on numerous versions of Ubuntu, including most recently 17.04, without problems. I recently freshly installed 17.10. (I have also tried this on another computer that I *updated* from 17.04 to 17.10, with the same results.)

The script you run to use Rubyripper starts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#    Rubyripper - A secure ripper for Linux/BSD/OSX
#    Copyright (C) 2007  Bouke Woudstra (rubyripperdev@gmail.com)

[snip: Licencing and disclaimer, etc.]

#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>

ICONDIR=[ENV['PWD'], "/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps"]
RUBYDIR=[ENV['PWD'], File.dirname(__FILE__), "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0"]

found_rrlib = false
RUBYDIR.each do |dir|
  if File.exist?(file = File.join(dir, '/rr_lib.rb'))
    require file; found_rrlib = true ; break
  end
end
if found_rrlib == false
  puts "The main program logic file 'rr_lib.rb' can't be found!"
  exit()
end

begin
    require 'gtk2'
rescue LoadError
    puts "The ruby-gtk2 library could not be found. Is it installed?"; exit()
end
```

When I run this, I get the return `The ruby-gtk2 library could not be found. Is it installed?`. The package `ruby-gtk2` is definitely installed:

```
rowand@desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install ruby-gtk2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ruby-gtk2 is already the newest version (3.1.8-6ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

What I think is going on is that the location of the relevant file or files under 17.10 is different to what the script is expecting, and different to where they were under 17.04. Therefore, I have tried editing the following line of the script, saving it, and then running it again.

```
RUBYDIR=[ENV['PWD'], File.dirname(__FILE__), "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0"]
```

Based on searches of `/usr`, I have tried the following:

```
RUBYDIR=[ENV['PWD'], File.dirname(__FILE__), "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0"]
RUBYDIR=[ENV['PWD'], File.dirname(__FILE__), "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby"]
RUBYDIR=[ENV['PWD'], File.dirname(__FILE__), "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/gtk2"]
RUBYDIR=[ENV['PWD'], File.dirname(__FILE__), "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0"]
```

None of them work. I keep getting the same error (`The ruby-gtk2 library could not be found. Is it installed?`).

The return of `sudo dpkg -L ruby-gtk2` is:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/gtk2
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/gtk2/base.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/gtk2.rb
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/gtk2.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/copyright
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/README
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/alphatest.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/apple-red.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/appwindow.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/background.jpg
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/builder.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/button_box.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-arc-negative.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-arc.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-clip-image.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-clip-rectangle.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-clip.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-curve-rectangle.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-curve-to.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-dash.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-fill-and-stroke.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-fill-and-stroke2.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-gradient.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-image-pattern.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-image.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-line-cap.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-line-join.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-long-lines.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-operator.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-path.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-pattern-fill.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-self-intersect.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-text-align-center.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-text-extents.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/cairo-text.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/changedisplay.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/clipboard.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/colorsel.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/common.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/demo.ui.gz
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/dialog.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/drawingarea.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/editable_cells.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/entry_completion.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/expander.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/floppybuddy.gif
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/gnome-applets.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/gnome-calendar.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/gnome-foot.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/gnome-fs-directory.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/gnome-fs-regular.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/gnome-gimp.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/gnome-gmush.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/gnome-gsame.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/gnu-keys.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/gtk-logo-rgb.gif
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/hypertext.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/iconview.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/images.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/item_factory.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/list_store.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/main.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/menus.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/panes.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/pixbufs.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/printing.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/rotated_text.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/ruby-gnome2-logo.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/sizegroup.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/stock_browser.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/textview.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/gtk-demo/tree_store.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/aboutdialog.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/aboutdialog2.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/alpha-demo.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/assistant.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/bindings.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/button.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/button2.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/buttonbox.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/cairo-pong.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/calendar.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/checkbutton.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/colorselection.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/combo_check.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/combobox.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/composited-windows.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/cursor.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/dialog.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/dialog2.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/dnd.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/dndtreeview.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/drag-move.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/drawing.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/entry.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/entrycompletion.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/expander.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/filechooser.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/fileselection.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/frame.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/gc.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/gdkscreen.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/gnome-logo-icon.png
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/helloworld.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/iconview.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/image.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/infobar.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/itemfactory.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/itemfactory2.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/keyboard_grab.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/label.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/linkbutton.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/listview.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/menu.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/misc_button.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/mouse-gesture.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/pangorenderer.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/pointer_grab.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/print.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/properties.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/radiobutton.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/recentchooserdialog.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/rgtk+cairo.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/scalebutton.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/settings.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/statusicon.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/stock.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/style_property.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/style_property.rc
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/t-gtkplug.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/t-gtksocket.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/test.xpm
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/textbuffer_serialize.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/threads.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/to_drawable.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/togglebutton.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/toolbar.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/tooltips.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/tree_combo.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/tree_progress.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/treemodelfilter.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/treeview.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/uimanager.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/uimanager2.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/uimanager2.xml
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/window.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/misc/xbm_cursor.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/3DRings.xpm
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/FilesQueue.xpm
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/Modeller.xpm
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/README
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/button.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/buttonbox.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/check-n.xpm
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/check-y.xpm
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/checkbutton.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/circles.xbm
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/colorselect.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/dialog.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/entry.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/filesel.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/fontselection.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/gammacurve.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/labels.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/layout.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/marble.xpm.gz
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/menu.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/notebook.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/pixmap.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/progressbar.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/radiobutton.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/range.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/reparent.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/rulers.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/sample.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/savedposition.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/scrolledwindow.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/shapedwindow.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/spinbutton.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/statusbar.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/test.xpm
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/testgtk.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/testgtkrc
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/testgtkrc2
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/togglebutton.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/toolbar.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/tooltips.rb
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/examples/testgtk/wmhints.rb
/usr/share/rubygems-integration
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.3.0
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.3.0/specifications
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.3.0/specifications/gtk2-3.1.8.gemspec
/usr/share/doc/ruby-gtk2/changelog.Debian.gz
```

**My question is:** what should I replace `/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0` with to get the Rubyripper script to correctly find the `ruby-gtk2` library that it is looking for? Or am I completely on the wrong track? If so, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines that are relevant here are:

```
begin
       require 'gtk2'
rescue LoadError
       puts "The ruby-gtk2 library could not be found. Is it installed?"; exit()
end
```

This catches the exception and throws away all the information you need to debug the problem.  If you replace that with just:

```
require 'gtk2'
```

You will get this error message:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- cairo-gobject (LoadError)
```

Which makes it clear how to fix the problem:

```
sudo apt install ruby-cairo-gobject
```

Hope that does the trick for you!

Rob